# Linear algebra - Dimension of subspace problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I found this question from a lecture slide on the GRE linear algebra section of the math subject test, and couldn't figure it out.

Suppose $V$ is a real vector space of finite dimension n.  Call the set of matrices from $V$ into itself $M(V)$.
Let $T∈ M(V)$.  Consider the two subspaces $U=\{X∈M(V);TX = XT\}$ and $W=\{TX−XT; X∈M(V)\}$.

Which of the following must be TRUE?

I. If $V$ has a basis containing only eigenvectors of $T$ then $U=M(V)$.

II.$\dim(U) +\dim(W) =n^2$.

III.$\dim(U)< n$.

I think that II must be false, but I can't figure out the truth of I or III. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you worked through any examples, say for $n = 2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\dim}{dim}$

1 is not necessarily true. For take $n = 2$, and let $T(e_1) = e_1$ and $T(e_2) = 2e_2$. Let $X$ be s.t. $X(e_1) = e_1$ and $X(e_2) = e_1 + e_2$. Then $TX(e_2) = T(e_1 + e_2) = e_1 + 2e_2$, but $XT(e_2) = X(2 e_2) = 2e_1 + 2e_2$. Then $TX \neq XT$.

2 is true. Consider the linear map $f: M(V) \to M(V)$ sending $X$ to $TX - XT$. Then we may write $W = \im(f)$ and $U = \ker(f)$. Then by the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim(U) + \dim(W) = \dim(M(V)) = n^2$.

3 is not necessarily true. For take $n > 1$ and $T =$ the identity. Then $U = M(V)$ so $\dim(U) = \dim(M(V)) = n^2 > n$.